# PHP repetindo dados do banco

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá. Estou fazendo um site para fins estudantis, levando em conta que a conexão com o banco de dados está perfeita, na hora de pegar os dados armazenados no banco, o PHP duplica o conteúdo na página. Como na imagem à seguir (Ignorem a imagem, pois o url dela é o mesmo para todas):

[![s][1]][1]

```
<?php 

            $server ='localhost';
            $user ='root';
            $password ='root';
            $dbname ='site_salgados';
            $port ='3306';

            $db_connect = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $dbname, $port);
            mysqli_set_charset($db_connect, "utf8");

            if ($db_connect->connect_error == true) {
            echo 'Falha ao se conectar! erro: ' . $db_connect->connect_error;

            } else {
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT nome, descricao FROM produtos";
                $result = $db_connect->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

                $nome = $row['nome']; 
                $descricao = $row['descricao']; ?>

                     <div class="container mt-5 mb-4 ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div>
                                    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                    <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $nome; ?></a></h6>
                                    <p><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div>
                                    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                    <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $nome; ?></a></h6>
                                    <p><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                <?php }
            }
            }

        ?>
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar? Estou tentando resolver este erro há algum tempo.

Comment: Estou usando o framework de CSS, Boostrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, entao do que eu vejo no teu codigo tu estas a fazer echo duas vezes a mesma variavel

```
<?php 

                $server ='localhost';
                $user ='root';
                $password ='root';
                $dbname ='site_salgados';
                $port ='3306';

                $db_connect = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $dbname, $port);
                mysqli_set_charset($db_connect, "utf8");

                if ($db_connect->connect_error == true) {
                echo 'Falha ao se conectar! erro: ' . $db_connect->connect_error;

                } else {
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT nome, descricao FROM produtos";
                    $result = $db_connect->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

                    $nome = $row['nome']; 
                    $descricao = $row['descricao']; ?>

                         <div class="container mt-5 mb-4 ">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div>
                                        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                        <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $nome;?></a></h6>
                                        <p><?php echo $descricao; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div>
                                        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                        <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $mesmo_nome_que_la_em_cima; ?></a></h6>
                                        <p><?php echo $mesma_descricao_que_la_em_cima; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php }
                }
                }

            ?>
```

Podes tentar o seguinte, mas geralmente recomendo separares o teu layout do teu controlador

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    { 
                     ?>
                      <div class="container mt-5 mb-4 ">
                          <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div>
                                           <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                           <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $row["nome"];?></a></h6>
                                           <p><?php echo $row["descricao"]; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                      <?php 
                           $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                      ?>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                       <div>
                                         <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="gallery/1.jpg"></a>
                                         <h6><a href="#"><?php echo $row["nome"];?></a></h6>
                                         <p><?php echo $row["descricao"]; ?></p>
                                         </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                <?php }
        }
      }

  ?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolvido! Obrigado por dedicar teu tempo me ajudando :D

Comment: Me considero Programador Junior em PHP por saber o básico e mais um pouco... Se não for pedir muito, poderia ser mais específico com "separar Layout do Controlador"?

Comment: Simples por em ficheiros o layout ou seja , o que a pessoa ve , em outros a parte logica o que a pessoa nao ve, e em vez de chamares todo o codigo dentro do html, cria uma funcao em php e chama somente essa funcao quando necessario, mas isto é se quiseres continuar so com php e html sem recorrer a frameworks, mais limpo e avançado ainda, é usares HTML , CSS para o layout , JavaScript para a interação, dinamismo e enviar os requests em AJAX ao teu controlador , ou seja o teu PHP, informa-te sobre a arquitetura MVC

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas! Tive um outro problema ao fazer do jeito que você me disse. Ao adicionar mais um elemento ao banco de dados, na página é criada uma div com h2 e um paragrafo, esperando que eu crie mais dois conteúdos no banco de dados. Como eu poderia fazer com que o PHP apenas criasse novos conteúdos na página com somente o que tem no banco? Um abraço e obrigado pela ajuda! (Vou editar a postagem e postar um print do que quero dizer)

Comment: Não edites a postagem, faz outra pergunta

Comment: Pronto. Espero que possam me responder antes que o público tóxico desse site faça com quem eu seja proibido de fazer novas perguntas.

Comment: @JoãoVictor Se você ficar fazendo edições na pergunta depois de aceita o próprio sistema vai o bloquear para fazer novas perguntas. Seu comentário foi injusto, nem os moderadores tem a prorrogativa de impedir que perguntas sejam feitas. Os moderadores e membros da comunidade tem a prerrogativa de fechar a pergunta ao perceberem falhas ou inconsistências na formulação da questão, mas isso não significa que a pergunta está definitivamente fechada. Se olhar no quadro logo abaixo da pergunta está descrito o motivo do fechamento caso você edite a pergunta ela segue para uma fila de análise...

Comment: ...fila essa que acabei de encontrar essa pergunta e então a pergunta será revisada e caso esteja clarificada com relação ao motivo do  fechamento ela será reaberta. Leia: [Minha pergunta foi fechada, não posso obter uma resposta ali?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7928/minha-pergunta-foi-fechada-n%c3%a3o-posso-obter-uma-resposta-ali). Tendo dúvidas sobre como perguntar [ask]. Dúvidas sobre o funcionamento do site, faça o nosso [tour].